# Grails Export plugin set column height

Tags: grails, export

I am using export plugin from grails. And I have this code in my controller:

```
    if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){ 
        response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Pour-Schedule.${params.extension}")
        List fields = ["id", "customer"] 
        Map labels = ["id": "Id", "customer": "Customer"]

        Map parameters = [title: "Customer List", "column.widths": [0.2, 0.3]] 

        exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, Customer.list(params), fields, labels, [:], parameters) }
```

The code column.widths will set the width of the column on the excel, pdf etc. Now How can I set the height of this column? I tried the column.height but its not working, so as row.height.

Can anyone help me please? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of my understanding the width of the rows is not supported, unfortunately.
See [API documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/export).

PDF export supports some additonal parameters which can be used just like the title attribute in the code sample above. The following parameters are supported:

- pdf.encoding (specifies font encoding, defaults to "Cp1252" (=latin 1), allowed values: "Cp1250", "Cp1252" (=latin 2), "Cp1257", "Identity-H", "Identity-V", "MacRoman") see http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/fonts/index.php for further information about encodings
- title.encoding (same as pdf.encoding but for title font)
- header.encoding (same as pdf.encoding but for header font)
- text.encoding (same as pdf.encoding but for text font)
- title.font.size (determines title font size, defaults to "10",allowed values: a number as String)
- header.font.size (determines header font size, defaults to "10", allowed values: a number as String)
- text.font.size (determines text font size, defaults to "10", allowed values: a number as String)
- font.family (determines global font family, allowed values: constants defined in http://www.1t3xt.info/api/com/lowagie/text/FontFactory.html)
- title.font.family (determines title font family, defaults to com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.HELVETICA, allowed values: constants defined in http://www.1t3xt.info/api/com/lowagie/text/FontFactory.html)
- header.font.family (determines header font family, defaults to com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.HELVETICA, allowed values: constants defined in http://www.1t3xt.info/api/com/lowagie/text/FontFactory.html)
- text.font.family (determines text font family, defaults to com.lowagie.text.FontFactory.HELVETICA, allowed values: constants defined in http://www.1t3xt.info/api/com/lowagie/text/FontFactory.html)
- title.font.style (determines title font style, defaults to "bold", allowed values: "bold", "italic", "normal", "bolditalic")
- header.font.style (determines header font style, defaults to "bold", allowed values: "bold", "italic", "normal", "bolditalic")
- text.font.style (determines text font style, defaults to "normal", allowed values: "bold", "italic", "normal", "bolditalic")
- border.color (determines table border color, defaults to: new Color(163, 163, 163), allowed values: a java.awt.Color object e.g. Color.RED)
- separator.color (determines table row separator color, defaults to: new Color(238, 238, 238), allowed values: a java.awt.Color object e.g. new Color(100, 100, 100))
- column.widths (specifies column widths in percent, defaults to equal size for all columns, allowed values: List of floats e.g.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot set the cell height, you can at least use line-breaks, in order to make a cell height bigger.